# Выборка непересекающихся данных таблицы из разных сессий

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Добрый день!

Есть абстрактная таблица (objects), объекты которой, необходимо регулярно проверять (раз в день). Данных около миллиона.

В ней 3 поля:

- id - идентификатор
- name - название
- checked_at - временная метка о последней проверке.

Есть некий скрипт, которых получает порцию данных:

```
SELECT * FROM objects WHERE checked_at < 'today'::timestamp LIMIT 100;
```

Из-за резкого увеличения количества объектов, возникла необходимость распараллелить данный процесс на N-скриптов (по факту на N-сессий).

Если это делать в "лоб", скрипты будут получать одинаковые данные, что не есть хорошо.

Вариант с ORDER BY RANDOM() тоже не подходит, так как при уменьшении количества объектов которые осталось проверить, данные опять будут пересекаться + на больших выборках он начинает тормозить.

Информации о блокировках на уровне строк, я не нашел (чтобы SELECT из другой сессии не смог прочитать залоченные данные).

Можно воспользоваться очередями или какими то менеджерами, но не хочется.
Хочется запустить просто N-скриптов и они параллельно проверили бы M-строк.

Использую Postgres 9.5.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Пронумеруйте процессы от 0 до N-1 и берите записи у которых остаток от деления ID на N равен номеру процесса (`where ... and id % N = X`). Работать будет во всех случаях, кроме ситуации если у вас id идут с равномерными пропусками, особенно плохо будет если размер этих пропусков кратен N.

Comment: Это была первая мысль о которой я подумал. Но как я писал ниже, может случится так, что один из процессов умрет или наоборот, сделает все быстрее, записи с N будут не проверенны.

Comment: @IvanSinyukov Такие ограничения надо указывать прямо в тексте вопроса. Можете попробовать конечно поиграться с `select for update skip locked` и возможно с ручными блокировками вроде pg_advisory_lock(). Но как бы вы это не делали, если воркеры могут падать вам все равно надо будет прямо в БД фиксировать факт того какие записи обработаны а какие нет, что бы при рестарте воркеров они брали только то что не видели.

Answer (score -1):

Если id монотонные, то в лоб это разбить на группы по id и запустить.
Каждая сессия по 10к элементов, например.

```
SELECT * FROM objects WHERE checked_at < 'today'::timestamp AND (id BETWEEN 1 AND 10000);
SELECT * FROM objects WHERE checked_at < 'today'::timestamp AND (id BETWEEN 10001 AND 20000);
```

и т.д.

Comment: Если пишешь ответ, то пиши информативнее чуток. Это похоже на комментарий, но никак не на ответ.

Comment: @Владимир, На что похоже не знаю, но это прямой ответ на поставленный вопрос, одно из решений. На комментарии у меня рейтинга пока не хватает.

Comment: После изменения ответ преобразился, но все-равно кто-то минус поставил.

Comment: Это не решение вопроса, так как мы не знаем точного количество запускаемых воркеров (сессий).

И постоянное изменение интервалов не есть хорошо.

К тому же, если один из воркеров, сделает все быстрее или по каким-либо причинам не сможет обрабатывать строки, получится, что эти строки не проверятся.

Comment: @Ivan Sinyukov, в задаче это не указано, нужно распараллелить обновление, т.е. разбить на части, я описал одно из возможных решений. ВЫборка по ид идет, так что пройдут все элементы.

Comment: Если программа аварийно завершается, то вы в состоянии это отследить, если не в состоянии, то пробежаться по миллиону строчек и найти не обработанные, не такая проблема, учитывая остальную нагрузку.